# Windows 7 Not Recognizing Any Hardware, Linux Recognizing Hardware

Tags: windows-7, windows, hardware-failure

I have a new desktop computer with two SSDs: one running Linux Mint 15 (SSD1), the other running Windows 7 (SSD2). My mint runs perfectly - USB wireless adapter is recognized, SSD2 (connected by SATA) is recognized and accessible through the filesystem, Ethernet works, etc.

However, my Windows 7 is not recognizing any of these devices - even plugging in a regular ethernet cable doesn't work. It seems that it's not recognizing any network adapters, and it also doesn't recognize SSD1, connected to the mainboard by SATA. I've installed, uninstalled, and reinstalled Windows multiple times, but the problem persists.

I used the Windows 7 CD to install Windows on a machine previously, and that time around, I didn't have any problems, which leads me to suspect that this might be a hardware issue, specifically with the mainboard. My mainboard is an MSI-7641 model, the 760GM-P34 FX. It uses an AMD Chipset and an AMD processor.

Can anyone suggest what might be wrong, and how to fix it?

Comment: have you installed the AMD SATA drivers?

Comment: No. What are they and what do they do? Can you give me a link?

Comment: 64bit: http://support.amd.com/en-us/download/chipset?os=Windows%208%20-%2064 and 32Bit: http://support.amd.com/en-us/download/chipset?os=Windows%208%20-%2032

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem was resolved by downloading drivers:

http://support.amd.com/en-us/download/chipset?os=Windows%208%20-%2064

http://us.msi.com/product/mb/760GM-P23--FX-.html

as well as the driver for an Edimax 7811Un wireless adapter. 
http://www.edimax.com/en/support_detail.php?pd_id=347&pl1_id=1&pl2_id=